# Сравнение с подсчётом

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вывод, сравнение

Дан массив из  чисел: 1, 2, . . .,  .
**Требуется для каждого элемента массива  посчитать количество элементов , стоящих
правее ( < ), но меньших него ( >  ).**
В первой строке записано целое число  (1 <=  <= 100).
Во второй строке через пробел записано  целых положительных чисел — значения элементов массива. Гарантируется, что значения элементов не превосходят 100.
Выведите  целых чисел через пробел: по порядку для каждого элемента входного массива выведите количество элементов, удовлетворяющих описанному выше условию.
Мой код вроде бы работает, но выводит какие-то странные значения.
К примеру, при N=3 и вводе 3 2 1 на выходе должно быть 2 1 0, а у меня вообще 1 2 3.
Посоветуйте, что можно сделать/исправить, пожалуйста :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int N, i, j, n;
    n=0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int b[10000];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            if((i<j)&&(b[i]>b[j])){
                n++;
                printf("%d", n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: А зачем вы прямо в цикле, не досчитав, выводите?..

Comment: То есть? Я же перебираю все элементы и вывожу для каждого

Comment: @dIm0n А при чем тут `main`? Там совсем другие ошибки.

Comment: @Mikhailo для переносимости должно быть `main(void)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно проверяете, неверно считаете и неверно выводите. Долго расписывать каждую ошибку, возьмите готовое решение.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int b[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int n = 0;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (b[i] > b[j]) n++;

        printf("%d ", n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А почему j должно быть больше i на 1? Получается, мы сразу не рассматриваем те элементы, которые левее искомого?

Comment: А зачем нам считать те, которые слева? В усливии же сказано - `i<j`. Вот только они нас и интересуют.